# How can I get the size of a string array?

Tags: android, file, directory, spinner

I have a text file, I use this code to split and process this content:

```
String[] array = s.split(",");
```

How I can get size of this array?

The text file filling dynamic, and I don't know size of the items.

I can get the size of `ArrayList<string>`, but this object is unuseable here.

```
public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();                    
myList =s.split(",");//error:cannot convert from String[] to ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: `array.length`? Or did I miss something...I'm not sure the coffee is working anymore

Comment: Are you wanting the amount of arrays you have? as in, Red, Blue, Orange = 3 strings... or 13 characters

Comment: @CaseyB : I disagree that this is in any way a duplicate of the question you linked. The OP of that question is asking about the philosophical decisions behind why the original Java developers didn't provide an encapsulated 'getter' method to return the size of an array. The OP here is simply asking how to find out the size of his/her array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want the amount of elements in this array `String[] array = s.split(",");` just do:

```
array.length
```

To convert this array to a list do this:

```
public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();                    
String[] array = s.split(",");
myList = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Comment: tnx, myList = Arrays.toList(stringArray);
has error:The method toList(String[]) is undefined for the type Arrays

Answer (score 2):

Look at this post and understand the difference between array and Arraylist

[Where is array's length property defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property)

To answer your question, you can get the size of the array by calling .length on it.

```
array.length
```

You should also look at this to learn more about arrays.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by the size of the items. you could use `array.length()` or `array.size()`, so for example maybe something like

`Integer arrayLength = (Integer) array.length();`

or

`Integer arrayLength = (Integer) array.size();`

i would imagine...

for more on how `size()` and `length()` are different please refer to [count vs length vs size in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300522/count-vs-length-vs-size-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 0):

In String There are two way of geting the length of String:-

```
String s; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   s.length();
}
```