# How does Java calculate length of primitive array?

Tags: java, arrays, char, primitive-types

**Code:**

```
char[] chars = "abcd".toCharArray();
System.out.println(chars.length);
```

**Question:** How is length calculate by Java here? Since char is not a Class, I am not sure where length is stored. If it isn't stored, is it calculated every time you do chars.length? (I presume not)

Comment: @RaulRene - You are right. I wasn't searching with the right words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing you wrote as `char[]` is an Object, an array, and has a public final field called `length`.  It is calculated *once* when the array in created.  Like all objects it also has a `toString(), notify()`, etc...

Comment: You are right. I was able to do chars.getClass() and it printed "class [C".

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7

> The public final field length, which contains the number of components
>   of the array. length may be positive or zero.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `chars.length` is returning the number of elements in the array.

Or am I missing the question?

Answer (score 0):

Even though `char` is not a Class/Object type in Java, an *array* of `char` actually is.  And the length is a (final) field of that class.  See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property) for more.