# Efficient method to find the second largest even int in an array

Tags: java, arrays, search, int

The assignment is to create a method that finds the second largest even int in an array of ints. I am restricted from using any methods from any libraries.

Here is my code that works for all cases:

```
public static int getSecondLargestEven(int[] ary) {


int i;

    aryLength = ary.length;
    int largestEven = -1;
    int secondLargestEven = -1;

    for (i = 0; i < aryLength; i++) {
        if (ary[i] % 2 == 0) {
            if (ary[i] > largestEven) {
                if (largestEven != -1)
                    secondLargestEven = largestEven;

                largestEven = ary[i];
            } else { 
                if (ary[i] != largestEven) {
                    if (secondLargestEven == -1 || ary[i] >= secondLargestEven) {
                        secondLargestEven = ary[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Prior to calling the methodI require the array to have more than one even else no method call.
So, when secondLargestEven == -1, I know there is a duplicate.

Is there a more efficient (less use of operators, less loops used, less memory allocation) way to accomplish the objective? How can I improve the logic of my code? How can I improve my code overall?
I don't like that I have to assign the magic number -1 to secondLargestEven and largestEven because they are technically named to hold EVENS. Would it be efficient to use a loop to assign a valid even integer in the array to both secondLargestEven and largestEven and THEN proceed to search? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For working code that you would like to improve (runtime, resources or general style/architecture), you'd be best served at [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your code seems to be efficient, in terms of performances, even if it isn't nice. Code elegance and best efficiency are often incompatible

Comment: @Joel I would argue that asymptotic efficiency is very compatible with elegance in most cases. Now making something use 1 byte less may make ugly code.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions about Best practices and  Performance belong to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

You can make the code cleaner by not explicitly checking for the case when the `largest` and `second` variables are equal to `-1`.

Just set these variables to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` before the loop - this is the same as assuming that there were two additional values in your array that come before all the others, and they both have the value `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

```
public static int secondLargestEven(int[] x) {

    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] % 2 == 0) {
            if (x[i] > largest) {
                second = largest;
                largest = x[i];
            } else if (x[i] > second) {
                second = x[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return second;

}
```

---

Edit -- I thought I'd throw in that you can remove one level of nesting by using a `continue` statement inside the loop to skip the cases where you have an odd integer, although some people would consider this more difficult to understand than the code above.

It's a tradeoff - you use explicit control flow inside the loop (bad) but you remove a nesting level (good).

```
public static int secondLargestEven(int[] x) {

    int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] % 2 != 0) 
            continue;
        if (x[i] > largest) {
            second = largest;
            largest = x[i];
        } else if (x[i] > second)
            second = x[i];
        }
    }

    return second;

}
```

---

Just a fun thought... in Haskell, this function can be written in one line

```
import Data.List (sort)

secondLargestEven = (!! 1) . reverse . sort . filter even
```

or, if you want to be more efficient

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Ord  (comparing)

secondLargestEven = (!! 1) . sortBy (comparing negate) . filter even
```

Comment: You can replace `Integer.MIN_VALUE` with `-2147483648` if you like, but in my opinion it makes the code less clear :)

Comment: Quick question: Is it more efficient to assign x.length to some variable of type int so I won't call .length() every time the loop iterates?

Comment: No, because `length` is a special attribute of the array, not a method, so you won't incur method call overhead. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property

Comment: I never thought of that. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

This is just-for-fun implementation:

```
public static int secondLargestEven(int[] array) {

    Set<Integer> evenSet = new TreeSet<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    for (int n : array) if (n % 2 == 0) evenSet.add(n);
    return new ArrayList<>(evenSet).get(1);
}
```

This method is extremely inefficient (I cant look at it) but returns second largest even number :)

Method works **only if** array has second largest even number.