# Java - How to check the array length via reflection (Field in class)

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following class:

```
public class GeneralClass
{
    public int x;
    public int[] arr = new int[3];
}
```

And the following logic:

```
public void loadClass(Class cls) {          
    Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {            
            if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                // How can I print the array length ?
            }
    }
}
```

How can I know what is the size (length) of the array ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Array.getLength`, however you need to provide a concrete instance so that's why I use `cls.newInstance()` (it's assuming there is a no-arg constructor)

```
public static void loadClass(Class<?> cls) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {          
        Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {      
                if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                    int length = Array.getLength(field.get(cls.newInstance()));
                    System.out.println(length);
                }
        }
    }
```

Note that if the field was static you could get it at a class level, so `int length = Array.getLength(field.get(null));` would work.

Comment: Seven answers, and only two understood what the question was asking, and only one provided the solution. Kudos.

Comment: @DavidConrad Scary, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The array field `arr` belongs to an instance of the class, hence its length cannot be determined by the `Field` object obtained via reflection as this is essentially class level metadata.

Comment: But we declared the array size in the class ? (it is not enogth) ?

Comment: @user3668129 Read the answer, especially this part: "[...] belongs to an _instance_ of the class". On an instance level you could read the size of the array (with the reflectional approach), on the class level you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
System.out.println(field.length);
```

Comment: there is no length in Field class

Comment: OP is asking about a reflectional access.

Answer (score 0):

the way to find the length of an array is `fields.length`

Comment: Did you try your answer ?
there is no "length" attribute in field (field is of type Field)

Comment: @user3668129 The syntax is `.length` to access the *length* of an array. Given by your code, `fields` is the array containing `Field` objects, so `fields` is what you are interested in.

Comment: No, `arr` is what Opie is interested in.

Answer (score -1):

Array length is fairly easy. It is

```
arrayName.length
```

So you can say :

```
System.out.print(   "length  is " +  arr.length  );
```

[Where is array's length property defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property)

Comment: ?
I'm getting "Field", so I cant do what you suggest me to do