# When to use length and when to use length()

Tags: java, size

I'm new to JAVA and I have a very simple question when I'm writing some codes. When should i use length and when should i use length()?

What's the difference between length and size?

Thank you!

Comment: It varies by type. Arrays have a length field, collections have a size() and String a length().

Comment: length is used for arrays and size() is used for collections

Comment: What @ElliottFrisch said.  Also, `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` have `length()`.  So does `File`.  So do many other less-used classes--see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index-files/index-12.html and scroll down to see what JRE-defined classes have `length()`.

Comment: For the god sake first search Google. Really it takes less time than posting this simple question here. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/arrays-length-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`length` --- **arrays** (`int[], double[], String[]`) ---- to know the length of the arrays.

`length()` --- **String related Object** (`String, StringBuilder etc`)to know the length of the String

`size()` ---  **Collection Object** (`ArrayList, Set etc`)to know the size of the Collection

as `length` is not a method its works on arrays not on objects.

`size()` is a method which work on collection frameworks as i said up there .

now String is not a direct array and also not a Collection that's why we also need a different one which is `length()`.

Comment: Oh i got it. But what's the difference between length and size?

Comment: @SeaBiscuit I think collections have `size()` because they're not necessarily in a sequence.  `Set` and `Map` collections don't have any order to them, and it doesn't seem right to talk about the "length" of one of those.  The consequence is that `List`, which is a subclass of `Collection`, has `size()` instead of `length()`, which takes some getting used to.  Maybe they should have defined `length()` as a synonym for `size()` for `List`... oh, well.

Comment: that is an nice explanation. I would be glad if you edit the answer to add this portion @ajb