# How to reference the highest index in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, int, element

```
public LibraryClass(int x) {
    bookShelf = new TextBook[x];
    for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
        bookShelf[i] = new TextBook("textbook" + i, 5);
    }
    nextBook = x - 1;  
    }
```

So this is my code, and whatever input we give the int x, for example 5, the max index would be 4. i could easily yes put a pointer on this position, but is there any other code which gives me the highest index number (NOT the highest element) to me?

Comment: Since you surely mean the "highest index number with an `TextBook` instance" you should write that in your question. Btw, prefer a `List` instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
int highest =  bookShelf.length -1;
```

Will give the result which is the highest index of array.

The reason for doing `-1` is array indices starts from zero. Hence the 5 indices array length will be `6`.

It seems you are looking for next and previous navigations, hence you might want to look at the data structure [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Answer (score 1):

The highest index of an array is always `array.length - 1` (or `bookShelf.length - 1` in your specific example).

Answer (score 0):

Just to repeat what others have said, use

```
array.length - 1
```

to get the highest index in the array. Or, given your example,

```
x - 1
```

To expand on what others have said, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/where-is-arrays-length-property-defined) SO question for more info on arrays and of course the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) for more functions on arrays.