# How to get the size of the file array in android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, size

I use this codes to get all Folders:

```
 File MyDir[] = getExternalCacheDirs();
```

And then I use these code to show the path:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MyDir[0].getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MyDir[1].getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, I wonder how to get the length of the file list, so I can use the for-loop to show all path

Like:

```
for (j = 0; j <= <size_of_the_list>; j += 1) { 
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),MyDir[j].getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MyDir** is an array, why dont you do:

```
// MyDir.length


for (j = 0; j < MyDir.length; j ++) { 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MyDir[j].getPath(),       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

?

Comment: but file array is same as others array?

Comment: ["you can use the built-in length property to determine the size of **any** array"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: oh fixed, I added length() instead of length, haha thz

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for the `length` property

```
for (j=0; j< MyDir.length; j++) { 

}
```

Here is a more detail [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/where-is-arrays-length-property-defined) about it

Answer (score 1):

It here:

```
public static long folderSize(File directory) {
    long length = 0;
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        if (file.isFile())
            length += file.length();
        else
            length += folderSize(file);
    }
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unfamiliar with arrays, I would suggest that you check out the [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) part of the nuts and bolts tutorial.

You are looking for the `length` property of the array:

```
for (j = 0; j < array.length; j += 1) { }
```

Note that you should be using `<` rather than `<=`, because there are `array.length` elements in the array, *not* `array.length + 1`. The last element of the array is `array[array.length - 1]` (assuming it is not empty).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, you can get the size of the array by calling .length on it.

```
array.length
```

You should also look at this to learn more about arrays.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html