# Finding the logical size of a Object array in Java

Tags: java

So unlike the int array where 0 is used as a placeholder, are there any placeholders for unused array indexes? I cannot figure out for the life of me how to use a for to find the logical size of my array. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, you may find the answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297899/where-is-arrays-length-property-defined)

Comment: Relying on array entry values like null or 0 as an indication for "not used" is something one should think about twice. Use a collection that can grow (e.g. ArrayList) to store just the relevant entries. If the index value is relevant (and you need "gaps"), consider using a Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default value of an entry in an object-typed array (`String[]`, `Thread[]`, `Object[]`, etc.) is `null`. That's the value analogous to your example of `0` in an `int[]` array.

E.g.:

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object[10];
System.out.println(objectArray[0] == null); // "true"
```

There's a difference between `0` in `int[]` and `null` in `Object[]`, of course: `0` is a valid `int` you can use for all the things you can use `int`s for. `null`, of course, is an object reference that doesn't refer to any object, so virtually the only thing you can do with that object reference is see whether it's `null`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Determining the "logical" size of an array can be tricky, primarily because in all cases the array must have valid values present. There are no "placeholder" values that mean "there is no value here".

Arrays of primitive integer types (`byte`, `char`, `short`, `int` and `long`) are initialized to the default value for those types, 0, as you note.

Arrays of floating point types (`float` and `double`) are initialized to the default value for those types, 0.0.

Arrays of `boolean` are initialized to `false`.

And arrays of any `Object` type are initialized to `null`.

In all these cases, a variable of the appropriate type can take the default value. So how does one tell whether those are real values that just happen to equal the default, or default values that haven't actually been provided by the application? You have to define what "placeholder" means for your application, and make sure you initialize your arrays accordingly.

One thing you might do, if your arrays are meant to hold numbers, is make them the corresponding `Object` type, i.e. use `Integer[]` rather than `int[]`. This will cause the array to be initialized to `null` rather than 0. Any 0 appearing in such an array would be a legitimate 0 rather than an artifact of initialization.

If `null` is a legitimate value, you might consider using `Optional<Foo>[] value =` rather than `Foo[] value =`. Then any array element that is `null` has definitely not been set. If your `value[n] != null`, you could check `value[n].isPresent()` to determine whether there's a real `Foo` held there or not.

There are lots of possibilities here, but the bottom line is that you have to make up your own mechanism. Nothing like a "placeholder value" is built into Java.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayref.length` is the size of the array. If un-unsed/un-assigned it will have `null` or `ZERO` based on type of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] a = new int [10];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
int logicalLength = 0;
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
    if(a[i] != 0){ // Here a[i] != 0 changes depending on the type of the array
        logicalLength++;
    }
}
System.out.println(logicalLength);
System.out.println(a.length);
```

In an array, he we don't assign any value, then the default value is stored. Default value for int is 0, double is 0.0 and String is null.